What does "LogonCredsAvailable" value 0x2 mean?
I'm trying to determine what type of boot a Windows install is set to use.  This computer cannot be booted.
In the Windows registry key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{D6886603-9D2F-4EB2-B667-1971041FA96B}
There is a registry value:
LogonCredsAvailable
If the value is "1" (0x00000001) then a PIN is used.
When I look at this device, the value is 0x00000002 (2).
I searched Google and found references to other people having the same code, but nothing saying what this code is.
Does anyone know what this value means?

I'm not sure I understand your question. Here's what I think you are asking:
"Which Credential Provider was used on this computer when it was still running?"
You can take a look at this registry value:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\LastLoggedOnProvider
This will provide the GUID of the most recently used Credential Provider on this device.
Then you can match this GUID with the ones you find at this location:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers

They may be asking if the value is related to the system not booting.
